# Reload tab with updated values

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `Tab Bar Controller`. There are two tab. First one is for showing some data on `Table View Controller` on the basis of some calculation. And the second tab is for changing values of variables which are used for the calculation of first tab's data.

Now if I change value in second tab and back to first tab it does not update the calculated value in first tab. But it does when I run the app again.

I have gone through many solutions but not worked for me. I used

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

But not worked for me.
 Please Help.

Comment: share some code so we can understand.

Comment: you need to pass data between this two controllers. reloadData is function which reload modified data .

Comment: you can use notification to notify second view controller about some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ViewWillAppear** to refresh the viewController every time you click on the tab.

As in tabViewController ViewController is loaded only once.So **ViewDidLoad** Method is called only first time *(As you say when your app restarts)*.

While **viewWillAppear** will be called every time you switch between the tabs.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     //refresh the view controller
}
```

Comment: Right!!!! Now I moved my code to viewWillAppear and it completely works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass data between two ViewController and Put your code inside

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely calling your `[self.tableView reloadData];`
 in viewDidLoad only. This is not called when you switch tabs since the views are already loaded. You can reload your tableView on `viewWillAppear:` like proposed by @Ved

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

otherwise, you can insert it in your setter. So every time your calculated value changes, your tableView will be reloaded.